# .htaccess directive behaves differently between Dev and Live environment

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess rewrite rule in my Live environment: RewriteRule ^.*/-v.*  /Dev1/index.php [L]
and this one in my local (Laragon) dev environment: RewriteRule ^.*/-v.*  /index.php [L] i.e. they rewrite to my index.php where I interrogate the URL. They are identical other than my root directory in dev is /Dev1/ (and just / in live).

In index.php I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to examine the 'freindly' incoming URL (which may have come from a search engine) e.g. [www.mysite.com/thingA/subthingB/-v](http://www.mysite.com/thingA/subthingB/-v).

In the live environment it works correctly, i.e. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] gives /thingA/subthingB/-v but the development environment just gives /Dev1/. The local dev environment uses Laragon on my PC.
Obviously I want to keep my dev and live code as identical as possible - any idea why the difference?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution ...
I didn't really get to the bottom of the problem - it seemed to be intermittent depending on the test data, and there seemed to be other strange things going on.
I have solved it by making 'localhost/dev1' my root directory in Laragon rather than 'localhost' - I hadn't realised how easy this was to do in Laragon. This will also help me tidy up a few other things.